# Get argument types of a function based on generic parameter values

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript it's possible for a function-argument to have a type based on another, generic argument:

```js
// foo(true, (v /* will be 1*/) => void 0)
// foo(false, (v /* will be 2*/) => void 0)
const foo = <T extends boolean>(a: T, cb: (v: T extends true ? 1 : 2) => void) => {}
```

On the other hand, you can get the type of a function via `typeof` and the Parameters using `Parameters<typeof foo>`:

```js
const foo =  (a: number, b: string) => {}
// Evaluates to (cb: (a: number, b: string) => void)
const baz = (cb: (...args: Parameters<typeof foo>) => void) => {}
```

How can I do this with functions where generics are used and the original function definition is unknown, I'm looking for something like this:

```js
// This function may be unknown or have overloads.
const foo = <T extends boolean>(args: T, cb: (v: T extends true ? 1 : 2) => void) => {}

const bar = <T extends Parameters<typeof foo>[0]>(
    args: T,
    // Doesn't work, just an example.
    // I imagined something like "give me the type of function 'foo' for when the first argument is 'T'"
    cb: Parameters<(typeof foo)[T]>[0]
) => {}

bar(true, (v /* should be 1 */) => void 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for are called [instantiation expressions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions), which were recently added in 4.7:

```
const foo = <T extends boolean>(args: T, cb: (v: T extends true ? 1 : 2) => void) => {}

const bar = <T extends Parameters<typeof foo>[0]>(
    args: T,
    cb: Parameters<typeof foo<T>>[1]
) => {}

bar(true, (v /* should be 1 */) => void 0);
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mx8P7m)